# how to deploy a vuejs/flask project on apache

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, apache2, gunicorn

I've created a simple project with vuejs as the frontend and flask as backend.

The project was constructed by following the example [here](https://appendto.com/2017/05/building-tutorial-search-app-vue/), thus the resultant file structure is like that the vuejs build files "dist" is on the same folder as that of the driving python script, run.py.

[image]

The project was tested and working fine locally now I ran into problems trying to deploy it on my Ubuntu server hosted by digitalocean.

I followed this [article](https://www.vioan.eu/blog/2016/10/10/deploy-your-flask-python-app-on-ubuntu-with-apache-gunicorn-and-systemd/) to learn how to deploy - the article was well written but I believed I need to change the apache config file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf) a little to specify the static files of my project as shown in the screenshot.

The question is how? I don't know. When I followed the article word by word and launched the web app, it showed errors like:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://my_website.com/static/js/manifest.0e78d562f6b86d93f516.js”. vue-amazon:1:1
```

static is a standard vuejs folder under "dist" in my file structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue has nothing to do with the way how Flask project is deployed - it's about the configuration of the vuejs frontend.

I need to adjust the setting of assetsPublicPath in vuejs's config file, to a proper location where the index.html can find the obfuscated javascripts.

For example, if my project is called "ABC", and i want the url looks like:

```
http://my-site.com/ABC
```

I need to have this in the vuejs config file:

```
env: require('./prod.env'),
index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist/index.html'),
assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist'),
assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
assetsPublicPath: '../../ABC/dist/',
```

before I run

```
npm run build
```